# Make Unity Usable/Downgrade

Tags: graphics-card, ubuntu-10.10, ubuntu-unity

After 20-ish hours of upgrading (slow Internet+forgetting to disable sleep mode) I finally finished upgrading my netbook to 10.10. Problem is, Unity doesn't work on it because of its extremely slow graphics. I tweaked the heck out of my interface, so I can get by, but my mom's been running the default install the whole time so she has nothing but a white screen on login.

How can I make Unity usable/downgrade to 10.04/some other option so that my mom can use the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use classic mode, or switch to KDE.